# Generating series of numbers in Python

Tags: python

Could someone please tell me why the row stops at 1 2 7 8 9? What should I change in the below code to get all the rows until 5 6 7 8 9?

We should start with some initial assumptions (a,b,c and d) and then generate the sequence of numbers until we reach the last row which is 5 6 7 8 9.

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5

while (e<10):
    print (a,b,c,d,e)
    e +=1
    
    if e==9:
        
        print(a,b,c,d,e)
        d+=1
        e=d+1
   
    elif d==8:
           
        c+=1
        d=c+1
        e=d+1
   
    elif c==7:
        b+=1
        c=b+1
        d=c+1
        e=d+1
    elif b==6:
        a+=1
        b=a+1
        c=b+1
        d=c+1
        e=d+1
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 6
1 2 3 4 7
1 2 3 4 8
1 2 3 4 9
1 2 3 5 6
1 2 3 5 7
1 2 3 5 8
1 2 3 5 9
1 2 3 6 7
1 2 3 6 8
1 2 3 6 9
1 2 3 7 8
1 2 3 7 9
1 2 3 8 9
1 2 4 5 6
1 2 4 5 7
1 2 4 5 8
1 2 4 5 9
1 2 4 6 7
1 2 4 6 8
1 2 4 6 9
1 2 4 7 8
1 2 4 7 9
1 2 4 8 9
1 2 5 6 7
1 2 5 6 8
1 2 5 6 9
1 2 5 7 8
1 2 5 7 9
1 2 5 8 9
1 2 6 7 8
1 2 6 7 9
1 2 6 8 9
1 2 7 8 9
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: It is just an assignment.

Comment: Then, post the assignment and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: There are infinitely many possibilities to change something to get the output (e.g. as simple as `print(5,6,7,8,9)`. Unless we know what you're allowed to change and what is the desired output, we can't help

Comment: The question is that how to generate the the series numbers with the initial values (a,b,c,d and e)...It is not homework it is just a question asked by a manager at work.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I have already accepted the answer.

Comment: @Ali If you did, then you must've unaccepted it again. Right now, no answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I change in the below code

Everything.

Just do it the normal way:

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb in combinations(range(1, 10), 5):
    print(*comb)
```

Or if that initial values thing is supposed to be more general:

```
from itertools import combinations

initial = 2, 4, 5, 7, 8

print(*initial)
combs = combinations(range(1, 10), 5)
initial in combs
for comb in combs:
    print(*comb)
```

Different way:

```
from itertools import combinations

initial = 2, 4, 5, 7, 8

for comb in combinations(range(1, 10), 5):
    if comb >= initial:
        print(*comb)
```

Comment: Your way is a lot better than mine. Thanks Kelly!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change all yours `elif` clauses to `if`.

When you enter in your last loop : a=1 b=2 c=7 d=8 e=9
So in the next : a = 1 b = 2 c = 8 d = 9 e = 10.
According to the new value of `e` you're exiting of the loop.
By changing your `elif`clauses to `if` clauses, you stay in the loop and update all blocking variables.

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

while (e < 10):
    print(a, b, c, d, e)
    e += 1

    if e == 9:
        print(a, b, c, d, e)
        d += 1
        e = d + 1

    if d == 8:
        c += 1
        d = c + 1
        e = d + 1

    if c == 7:
        b += 1
        c = b + 1
        d = c + 1
        e = d + 1
    if b == 6:
        a += 1
        b = a + 1
        c = b + 1
        d = c + 1
        e = d + 1
```

Comment: The only issue is that the codes generates until 5 6 8 9 10, while the last row should be 5 6 7 8 9. 10 is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `elif` and the internal variables are different you can find this error because one of the above conditions may occur before the one you want.

Just change the `elif` with a simple `if` to solve the problem.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
e = 5

while (e < 10):

    print(a, b, c, d, e)

    e += 1

    if e == 9:

        print(a, b, c, d, e)
        d += 1
        e = d + 1

    if d == 8:

        c += 1
        d = c + 1
        e = d + 1

    if c == 7:

        b += 1
        c = b + 1
        d = c + 1
        e = d + 1

    if b == 6:

        a += 1
        b = a + 1
        c = b + 1
        d = c + 1
        e = d + 1
```